# Paste - empty columns

Tags: unix, paste

I want to paste columns of three files. The middle files has one line empty. How to set the "tab" in this place?

file1

```
B 
B
B
```

file2

```
58399.9865 58468.6631 58434.3248

56972.1692 56975.0525 56973.6108
```

file3

```
22452
29000
1165
```

paste file1 file2 file3 > desired_result

output:

```
B   58399.9865 58468.6631 58434.3248    22452
B       29000
B   56972.1692 56975.0525 56973.6108    1165
```

29000 is from the last file in paste command and I would like to align it with 22452 and 1165

Desired output:

```
B   58399.9865 58468.6631 58434.3248    22452
B                                       29000
B   56972.1692 56975.0525 56973.6108    1165
```

OUTPUT after advise:

```
B  58399.9865 58468.6631 58434.3248  22452
B  29000
B  56972.1692 56975.0525 56973.6108  1165
```

Comment: I don't get it, there have to be 2 tabs between 2 and 5 or columns won't be aligned. It looks like this: `1TABaTAB4`, `2TABTAB5`, `3TABcTAB6`. And `paste` puts these 2 tabs be default.

Comment: I added the problem in my original files

Comment: Post correct input and desired output.

Comment: I editted my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$  paste file* | column -s "$(printf '\t')" -t
B  58399.9865 58468.6631 58434.3248  22452
B                                    29000
B  56972.1692 56975.0525 56973.6108  1165
```

Comment: Thank you it helped me with other align problems but the number 29000 is in the "second" column.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you have a question?

Comment: I got the output that I added to my question as OUTPUT after advise.

Comment: @Alex: ok, it may be because you don't use `Bash` but shell that doesn't understand `$'\t'` What shell and OS do you use?

Comment: I got the same result as before. I give a command in the file and I wrote `bash command.sh` and the result was the same too. I have linux Mint. $SHELL --version
GNU bash, verze 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Then I don't know what problem might be. `column` comes from util-linux. Do you have it installed and if yes in what version?

Comment: I don't know how to check it. It doesn't matter I use tab manually. The command from you helped me with something else. Many thanks.